# Unable to use TempData more than once even after using TempData.Keep() asp.net core mvc

Tags: c#, html, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, middleware

I have an mvc project that will pass a `tempdata["username"]`  in my middleware. But when debugging my middleware in the `if(tempdata.ContainsKey("username")`, I noticed that it only enters that if statement once and never enters it again. I read this article that explains how to use `TempData` and how to keep the data to be able to use it more than once but in my case it does not work. Is there something that I am missing to achieve this?

On my application I have 4 pages, on the home controller it will ask me to enter a username. When I do it then passes the tempdata in the middleware and enters the if statement. When proceeding to the post method and am on a new page it will not hold any value. So basically on the 3rd request tempdata gets deleted. How do I fix this so it can be passed throughout all my pages?

`HomeController`:

```
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        // Gather IP

       var userip = Request.HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress;


        _logger.LogInformation("IP address of user logged in: {@IP-Address}", userip);

        // Call AddressService API

         var result = _addressServiceClient.SampleAsync().Result;
        _logger.Log(LogLevel.Information, "Home Page...");

        return View();
    }


        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult AddressValidate(IFormCollection form)
        {
            // if radio button was checked, perform the following var request.

            // username

            username = form["UserName"];
            TempData["username"] = username;
            TempData.Keep("username");

            //HttpContext.Items["username"] = username;

            string status = form["Status"];

            _logger.LogInformation("Current user logged in: {@Username}", username);
          

            switch (status)
            {
                case "1":
                    _logger.LogInformation("Address entered was valid!");
                    break;
                case "2":
                    _logger.LogError("Address entered was invalid!");
                    ViewBag.Message = string.Format("You did not enter your address correctly! Please enter it again!");
                    return View("Index");
                case "3":
                    _logger.LogError("Invalid Address");
                    throw new Exception("Invalid Address");
                    
            }

            var request = new AddressRequest
            {

                StatusCode = Convert.ToInt32(status),
                Address = "2018 Main St New York City, NY, 10001"
            };


            var result = _addressServiceClient.ValidateAddress(request).Result;


            return RedirectToAction("SecIndex", "Second");
        }
```

`middleware`:

```
    public class CorrelationIdMiddleware
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
        private readonly ILogger _logger;
        private readonly ITempDataDictionaryFactory _tempDataDictionaryFactory;
        public CorrelationIdMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, ITempDataDictionaryFactory tempDataDictionaryFactory)
        {
            _next = next;
            _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<CorrelationIdMiddleware>();
            _tempDataDictionaryFactory = tempDataDictionaryFactory;
        }

        public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
        {
            string correlationId = null;
            string userName;
            var tempData = _tempDataDictionaryFactory.GetTempData(context);

            var key = context.Request.Headers.Keys.FirstOrDefault(n => n.ToLower().Equals("x-correlation-id"));
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(key))
            {
                correlationId = context.Request.Headers[key];
                _logger.LogInformation("Header contained CorrelationId: {@CorrelationId}", correlationId);
            }
            else
            {
                if (tempData.ContainsKey("username"))
                {
                    userName = tempData["username"].ToString();
                    context.Response.Headers.Append("X-username", userName);
                }

                correlationId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                _logger.LogInformation("Generated new CorrelationId: {@CorrelationId}", correlationId);
            }
            context.Response.Headers.Append("x-correlation-id", correlationId);
            using (LogContext.PushProperty("CorrelationId", correlationId))
            {
                await _next.Invoke(context);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Peek when you always want to retain the value for another request. Use Keep when retaining the value depends on additional logic.

In your case you have to use Peek. Instead of var val= TempData["username"] use val = TempData.Peek("username");

When you call val= TempData["username"] , under hood, after returnig data  it
automaticaly calls TempData.Remove("username").

Comment: THank you! I looked up the implementation for Peek() and commented out the line `TempData.Keep("username")` and did `TempData["username"] = username;` and `var val = TempData.Peek("username");` then `TempData.Peek("username");` I get the same issue. So from the first page transitioning to the second page it is fine. But when I click on a button on the second page to transition to the 3rd page, the if statement condition (tempdata) in the middleware  is not hit. Am I not implementing peek correctly?

Comment: Im sorry, I am not using `var val = TempData["username"];`. Currently I have `username = form["UserName"]` which will hold the value that the user entered in the textbox. Then I have `TempData["username"] = username;` followed by `var val = TempData.Peek("username");`. However, like this I still get the same result.

Comment: @MarkCo I mean in your middleware instead of  userName = tempData["username"].ToString(); use  userName =tempData.Peek("username").ToString();

Comment: Oh I see, will implement this. So in the homecontroller, should I leave it how it is already `username = form["UserName"];` followed by `TempData["username"] = username;` and lastly followed by `TempData.Keep("username");` or do I need to make some modifications in the homecontroller as well?

Comment: @MarkCo Don't use TempData.Keep("username"); at all. Check my answer update

Comment: Thank you!! It worked! I completely removed .Keep() and just left the first two lines as it was in the homecontroller and implemented it as you suggested in the middleware!

Comment: I just noticed that when I started again the application that in the middleware the if statement is hit and is using the username that was entered at in the previous application run. (So i.e. I run the app in the textbox I enter "user1" and pass through all the pages. Then I close the app and when I restart the app again, in the middleware the username will still be "user1" until the user enters a value in the textbox field). Is there a way to clear it out at the end of the application?

Comment: @MarkCo Yes, you can use TempData.Remove("username")  to clear completely when you don't need it  or maybe just use  var val=TempData["username"] if it is the last time you need it.

Comment: How would I put it at the end of the application so that way it can completely remove it so at the start it isn't the old username? Would I need to use that in the very last controller of my mvc project and perform `TempData.Remove("username")`?

Comment: TempData.Remove("username") is the most reliable way ,  but I can't tell you where to put it  since I don't know your application logic. You will have to decide it. It could take some debugging too.

Comment: Awesome thank you for the explanation! I'll see where it would be best to remove it! Thanks again :)